# Maximum sub array using D&C/Recursion

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, divide-and-conquer, kadanes-algorithm

I want to implement Maximum Sub Array problem with an algorithm that exhibits (n log n):

Find the maximum contigous sub array, or maximum sum of contiguous elements in the array.

Assumption:not all elements are negative numbers

---

I have somewhat working solution; the problem is with the overlapping center array, and the appropriate indexes that designate overlapping sub problems, some arrays Im getting the right answer on other not.

---

Just for comparison & for cheking correctness I implemented a solution known as Kadane’s algorithm 
(I believe the complexity is Omega(n)).

This is Kandane’s algorithm(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_subarray_problem):

---

```
 public static void Kadane(int array[]) {
        int max_ending_here = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            max_ending_here = max_ending_here + array[i];
            max_so_far = Math.max(max_so_far, max_ending_here);
        }
        System.out.println("Kadane(int array []): " + max_so_far);
    }
```

---

My recursive implementation, that uses divide & conquer to compare sub array's max's , then make's recursive call on the sub array that has the max, until the recursion ends

```
public static void findMaxSubArray(int[] array, int lowIndex, int highIndex) {

        int mid = 0;
        int arrayLength = 0;
        int maxEndingHere = 0;

        if (array == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException();
        } else if 
                //base condition 
           (array.length < 2 || (highIndex==lowIndex)) {
            maxLowIndex = lowIndex;
            maxHighIndex = highIndex;
            System.out.println("findMaxSubArray(int[] array, int lowIndex, int highIndex)");
            System.out.println("global Max Range, low:" + maxLowIndex + " high: " + maxHighIndex);
            System.out.println("global Max Sum:" + globalMaximum);
        } else {
            System.out.println();
            int lowMidMax = 0;
            int midHighMax = 0;
            int centerMax = 0;
            //array length is always the highest index +1 
            arrayLength = highIndex + 1;

            //if even number of elements in array 
            if (array.length % 2 == 0) {
                mid = arrayLength / 2;
                System.out.println("low: " + lowIndex + " mid: " + mid);
                for (int i = lowIndex; i < mid; i++) {
                    System.out.print(array[i] + ",");
                }
                //calculate maximum contigous array encountered so far in low to mid indexes 
                for (int i = lowIndex; i < mid; i++) {
                    maxEndingHere = maxEndingHere + array[i];
                    if (maxEndingHere < 0) {
                        maxEndingHere = 0;
                    }

                    if (globalMaximum < maxEndingHere) {
                        //new maximum found 
                        globalMaximum = lowMidMax = maxEndingHere;
                        lowIndex = i;
                    }

                }
                //end low mid calc 

                for (int i = mid; i <= highIndex; i++) {
                    System.out.print(array[i] + ",");
                }
                System.out.println("mid: " + mid + " high: " + highIndex);
                //calculate maximum contigous array encountered so far in mid to high indexes 
                for (int i = mid; i <= highIndex; i++) {
                    maxEndingHere = maxEndingHere + array[i];
                    if (maxEndingHere < 0) {
                        maxEndingHere = 0;
                    }

                    if (globalMaximum < maxEndingHere) {
                        //new maximum found 
                        globalMaximum = midHighMax = maxEndingHere;
                        mid = i;
                    }

                }
//end mid high calc
                //calculate maximum contigous array encountered so far in center array
                int lowCenter = mid -1;
                int highCenter = highIndex -1;

                System.out.println("lowCenter: " + lowCenter + " highCenter: " + highCenter);
                for (int i = lowCenter; i < highCenter; i++) {
                    System.out.print(array[i] + ",");
                }
                //calculate maximum contigous array encountered so far in low to mid indexes 
                for (int i = lowCenter; i < highCenter; i++) {
                    maxEndingHere = maxEndingHere + array[i];
                    if (maxEndingHere < 0) {
                        maxEndingHere = 0;
                    }

                    if (globalMaximum < maxEndingHere) {
                        //new max found
                        globalMaximum = centerMax = maxEndingHere;
                        lowCenter = i;

                    }

                }
                //end center calc 
                //determine which range contains the maximum sub array 
                //if lowMidMax <= midHighMax and centerMax
                if (lowMidMax >= midHighMax && lowMidMax >= centerMax) {
                    maxLowIndex = lowIndex;
                    maxHighIndex = mid;
                    //recursive call
                    findMaxSubArray(array, lowIndex, mid);
                }
                if (midHighMax >= lowMidMax && midHighMax >= centerMax) {
                    maxLowIndex = mid;
                    maxHighIndex = highIndex;
                    //recursive call
                    findMaxSubArray(array, mid, highIndex);
                }
                if (centerMax >= midHighMax && centerMax >= lowMidMax) {
                    maxLowIndex = lowCenter;
                    maxHighIndex = highCenter;
                    //recursive call
                    findMaxSubArray(array, lowCenter, highCenter);
                }

            }//end if even parent array 
            //else if uneven array 
            else {
                mid = (int) Math.floor(arrayLength / 2);
                System.out.println("low: " + lowIndex + " mid: " + mid);
                for (int i = lowIndex; i < mid; i++) {
                    System.out.print(array[i] + ",");
                }
                //calculate maximum contigous array encountered so far in low to mid indexes 
                for (int i = lowIndex; i < mid; i++) {
                    maxEndingHere = maxEndingHere + array[i];
                    if (maxEndingHere < 0) {
                        maxEndingHere = 0;
                    }

                    if (globalMaximum < maxEndingHere) {
                        //new maximum found 
                        globalMaximum = lowMidMax = maxEndingHere;
                        lowIndex = i;
                    }

                }
                //end low mid calc
                System.out.println("mid+1: " + (mid + 1) + " high: " + highIndex);
                for (int i = mid + 1; i <= highIndex; i++) {
                    System.out.print(array[i] + ",");
                }
                //calculate maximum contigous array encountered so far in mid to high indexes 
                for (int i = mid + 1; i <= highIndex; i++) {
                    maxEndingHere = maxEndingHere + array[i];
                    if (maxEndingHere < 0) {
                        maxEndingHere = 0;
                    }

                    if (globalMaximum < maxEndingHere) {
                        //new maximum found 
                        globalMaximum = midHighMax = maxEndingHere;
                        mid = i;
                    }

                }
                //end mid high calc
                //calculate maximum contigous array encountered so far in center array
                int lowCenter =  mid;
                int highCenter = highIndex -1;

                System.out.println("lowCenter: " + lowCenter + " highCenter: " + highCenter);
                for (int i = lowCenter; i < highCenter; i++) {
                    System.out.print(array[i] + ",");
                }
                //calculate maximum contigous array encountered so far in low to mid indexes 
                for (int i = lowCenter; i < highCenter; i++) {
                    maxEndingHere = maxEndingHere + array[i];
                    if (maxEndingHere < 0) {
                        maxEndingHere = 0;
                    }

                    if (globalMaximum < maxEndingHere) {
                        //new max
                        globalMaximum = centerMax = maxEndingHere;
                        lowCenter = i;
                    }

                }
                //end center calc 

                //determine which range contains the maximum sub array 
                //if lowMidMax <= midHighMax and centerMax
                  if (lowMidMax >= midHighMax && lowMidMax >= centerMax) {
                    maxLowIndex = lowIndex;
                    maxHighIndex = mid;
                    //recursive call
                    findMaxSubArray(array, lowIndex, mid);
                }
                if (midHighMax >= lowMidMax && midHighMax >= centerMax) {
                    maxLowIndex = mid;
                    maxHighIndex = highIndex;
                    //recursive call
                    findMaxSubArray(array, mid, highIndex);
                }
                if (centerMax >= midHighMax && centerMax >= lowMidMax) {
                    maxLowIndex = lowCenter;
                    maxHighIndex = highCenter;
                    //recursive call
                    findMaxSubArray(array, lowCenter, highCenter);
                }


            }//end odd parent array length 
        }//end outer else array is ok to computed 

    }//end method
```

---

Results : using array subArrayProblem1 = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8};

**Kadane(int array []): 36**
low: 0 mid: 4
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,mid: 4 high: 7
lowCenter: 6 highCenter: 6

findMaxSubArray(int[] array, int lowIndex, int highIndex)
global Max Range, low:7 high: 7
**global Max Sum:36**
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)

Issues although the global max sum is correct when compared to Kadane, the low index & high index range reflects the last recusive call.

Results : using array subArrayProblem = {100, 113, 110, 85, 105, 102, 86, 63, 81, 101, 94, 106, 101, 79, 94, 90, 97};

Kadane(int array []): 1607
low: 0 mid: 8
100,113,110,85,105,102,86,63,mid+1: 9 high: 16
101,94,106,101,79,94,90,97,lowCenter: 16 highCenter: 15

findMaxSubArray(int[] array, int lowIndex, int highIndex)
global Max Range, low:16 high: 16
global Max Sum:1526

The global max is not correct, note the difference is actually 1 element , which is the element 81

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.The implementation of Kadane's algorithm is wrong, it will fail on an array with some negative numbers.
correct one should look like :

```
 public static void Kadane(int array[]) {
        int max_ending_here = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            max_ending_here = Math.max(array[i], max_ending_here + array[i]);
            max_so_far = Math.max(max_so_far, max_ending_here);
        }
        System.out.println("Kadane(int array []): " + max_so_far);
    }
```

And many bugs in  your code, like:

2.`maxEndingHere` should be initialized to 0 before you calculate the answer for:

```
[lowIndex,mid)
[mid, highIndex]
[lowCenter, highCenter]
```

now it only gets initialized before the first iteration.

3.`lowCenter` should be initialized to `lowIndex`

4.The program is unnecessarily long and complicated ... I don't know if i missed any more bugs...

Comment: Your absolutely right regarding Kandane's algo for negative numbers, Im going to cleanup me coe and post the correct answer to D&C solution of max sub array

Answer (score 2):

A cleaner way to find subarray with the maximum sum (D/C recursive way) :

```
// A Divide and Conquer based Java solution
// To find a subarray with the maximum sum

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

class MaxSubArray {

    private static Result maxCrossingSum(int arr[], int l, int m, int h) {

        int sum = 0;
        int maxLeft = 0;
        int leftSum = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        for (int i = m; i >= l; i--) {
            sum = sum + arr[i];
            if (sum > leftSum) {
                leftSum = sum;
                maxLeft = i;
            }
        }

        sum = 0;
        int rightSum = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        int maxRight = arr.length - 1;
        for (int i = m + 1; i <= h; i++) {
            sum = sum + arr[i];
            if (sum > rightSum) {
                rightSum = sum;
                maxRight = i;
            }
        }

        return new Result(maxLeft, maxRight, leftSum + rightSum);
    }

    private static Result maxSubArray(int[] A, int low, int high) {

        if (low == high) {
            return new Result(low, high, A[low]);
        }

        int mid = (low + high) / 2;

        Result leftSubArray = maxSubArray(A, low, mid);
        Result rightSubArray = maxSubArray(A, mid + 1, high);
        Result maxCrossingSubArray = maxCrossingSum(A, low, mid, high);

        int leftSum = leftSubArray.sum;
        int rightSum = rightSubArray.sum;
        int crossSum = maxCrossingSubArray.sum;

        if (leftSum > rightSum && leftSum > crossSum) {
            return new Result(leftSubArray.low, leftSubArray.high, leftSubArray.sum);
        } else if (rightSum > leftSum && rightSum > crossSum) {
            return new Result(rightSubArray.low, rightSubArray.high, rightSubArray.sum);
        } else {
            return new Result(maxCrossingSubArray.low, maxCrossingSubArray.high,
                maxCrossingSubArray.sum);
        }
    }

    public static class Result {

        public int low;
        public int high;
        public int sum;
        public Result(int low, int high, int sum) {
            this.low = low;
            this.high = high;
            this.sum = sum;
        }

    }

    /* Driver program to test maxSubArray */
    public static Result maxSubArray(int[] arr) {
        return maxSubArray(arr, 0, arr.length - 1);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String[] arrString = sc.nextLine().split(" ");

        int n = arrString.length;

        int[] arr = new int[n];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            arr[i] = Integer.parseInt(arrString[i]);
        }

        Result result = maxSubArray(arr);

        int[] subArray = new int[result.high - result.low + 1];
        int j = 0;
        for (int i = result.low; i <= result.high; i++) {
            subArray[j++] = arr[i];
        }

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(subArray));
        System.out.println("Sum : " + result.sum);
    }
}
```